# Template runs fine with pdfLatex but not with pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, windows

When I try to compile [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/11340896krsxrvvmdbjc#/42814976/) in my new laptop (which uses Windows 10 64-bit) using `pdfLatex`, it works fine but whenever I try to do so using `pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex` it shows error which was not the case for my old computer (which uses Windows 7 32-bit).

**However, if I transfer all the files from my old computer to the new laptop, it runs even with `pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex`**.

### **The Error**

The error message is,

```
I couldn't open database file aomsample.bib
----line 140 of file aomart.aux
 : \bildata{aomsample
 :             }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
The style file: aomalpha.bst
I found no database files---while reading file aomart.aux
.
.
.
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Drive did not succeed.
```

### **Question**

Is it possible to compile the above linked latex file using `pdflatex+MakeIndex+BibTex` also? If so how?

Comment: Copying links from a Google search page is usually not ideal (look at the URL).  Which error do you get?

Comment: if you want help with an error it helps if you say what the error message is.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Link edited and error message added.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: See the edited question.

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the file `aomsample.bib` as well, and that it was placed in the same folder as the `.tex` file?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Actually when I ran the file on my old computer I didn't download any file at all. I simply copied the template and then compiled. So, I did the same in my laptop also.

Comment: As long as you're only doing the `pdflatex` part it will be fine, and it will also be fine if you comment out the `\bibliography` line, or remove the `\cite` commands. But if you  run `bibtex` after `pdflatex` on that specific `.tex` file, I have no idea why you wouldn't get that error, assuming that no `.bib` file is present. Anyways, the answer to your question is as I alluded to above: you need to have `aomsample.bib` in the same folder as your `.tex` file.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: But in my computer I don't have `aomsample.bib` at all. Why then it compiles perfectly?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: When I compiled the document using `pdfLatex` in my laptop I did not comment out `\bibliography` line nor did I remove the `\cite` commands. Still it compiled perfectly.

Comment: As I said, as long as you *only* compile with `pdflatex`, it will work. But the moment you include `bibtex` it fails. The error you show is from `bibtex`, not `pdflatex`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Is there anything that I can do other than using `aomsample.bib`? In my older computer even though I uninstall `bibtex` from both MiKTeX Package Manager (admin) and MiKTeX Package Manager the document still runs fine and generates the `.bbl` file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66440/discussion-between-torbjorn-t-and-user-170039).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you see comes from `bibtex`, and it's telling you that the specified `.bib` file is missing. Hence, just download `aomsample.bib` and place it in the same folder as your `.tex` file.